# Grant 'Log on as a service' permissions to a Network Service account for specific machine

Tags: windows, networking, permissions

Is it possible to grant 'Log on as a service' permissions to a Network Service account for specific machine or domain and restrict it for Network Service accounts from all other machines or domains?

[Properties: Log on as a service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voJgc.png)

For example, when I add DOMAIN\Network Service user to the list on the screenshot above, it automatically converts to Network Service user. Does it mean that there is no possibility to restrict 'Log on as a service' access to Network Service user from another machine or domain?

Comment: Unclear: Grant or restrict? Better rephrase the question.

Comment: I would like to restrict access on some machine to Network Service users from all machines, except specific one.

Comment: This can be done with firewall rules.